# How to pass id to function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have created a datatable showing a list of persons and their details. When the datatable is clicked, it has to show the entity of the single person with their details but my problem is, when I click the datatable it is opening a chat box showing the entity of the last clicked person changing all other chat box details.

1. How can I limit the append directive, that is, one chatbox for one id?
2. How to display the name of the particular person without changing the older chat box entity?

Here is the link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTWcZQjlAda0KQ9sjFzI?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ListController">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Reknown</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="item in artists" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <td ng-click="AppendText($index)"><span value="{{artists.indexOf(item)}}"></span>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td ng-click="AppendText($index)"><span value="{{artists.indexOf(item)}}"></span>
                  <h5>{{item.shortname}}</h5></td>
                <td ng-click="AppendText($index)"><span value="{{artists.indexOf(item)}}"></span><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                <td ng-click="AppendText($index)"><span value="{{artists.indexOf(item)}}"></span>{{item.reknown}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-directive-placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plunker link not working

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VTWcZQjlAda0KQ9sjFzI?p=preview

Comment: Change the `$('.my-directive-placeholder').append(directiveElement);` into `$('.my-directive-placeholder').html(directiveElement);`

Comment: @ Huy Hoang Pham  I tried your suggestion but now the other chat box are  not created. I want like facebook, the older chat box has to stay and the new chat box has to show the detail of the person.